# NTLM with java client give 401 error

Tags: java, ntlm

When I used NTLM in browser it works fine. But when the same URL is accessed by Java client then it gives 401 error. Any idea why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The [401 response is normal in this situation](http://www.innovation.ch/personal/ronald/ntlm.html). It returns with headers telling you what authentication mechanisms are available. You need to respond on the *same TCP connection* with the appropriate repeated HTTP request with headers set up with NTLM authentication answer. I suggest you use a HTTP client that can deal with this on its own. It is not trivial to get this right.

Comment: I am using proper http client which handle it..but in thrid request it gives 401 as NTLM use three way handshaking

Answer (score 0):

You may have been bitten by this (old) bug: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7176784

It was fixed in:

- Java 6 update 60 (only available through extended support from Oracle)
- Java 7 update 6
- Java 8 (build 45)